# How to update specific item in Firebase Recyclerview Adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have a list of items that I am loading with Firebase recycler view UI library adapter, now I want to update/refresh a single element in these items from another activity from client side (not from database)? How can I do that?

MyViewholder:

```
public class LessonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView title;
    public TextView short_title;
    public ImageView lessonIconView;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Lesson, LessonViewHolder> mAdapter;


    public LessonViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardTitle);
        lessonIconView =(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lesson_icon);
        short_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
    }
    public void bindToPost(Lesson post) {

        //  Log.d("Post", String.valueOf(post));
        if(post.getTitle() !=null)
        {
            title.setText(Html.fromHtml(post.getTitle()));
        }
        if(post.getShort_title()!=null) {

            short_title.setText(Html.fromHtml(post.getShort_title()));
        }
        if (post.getIcon() != null) {
            if(post.getColor()!=null) {
                TextDrawable drawableHindi = TextDrawable.builder()
                .buildRound(String.valueOf(getLayoutPosition() + 1), Color.parseColor(post.getColor()));
                lessonIconView.setImageDrawable(drawableHindi);
            }
            else {
                Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(post.getIcon()).into(lessonIconView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Fragment:

```
LessonViewHolder.class, ref) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final LessonViewHolder viewHolder, final Lesson model, final int position) {

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppEventsLogger logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(getActivity());
                logger.logEvent("ClickedLessonItem;"+ Locale.getDefault()+";"+position);
            }
        }
```

In detail explanation:

I am loading items from Firebase database through Firebase ui adapter, and now on click of one item it opens a web view activity, and after `onPageStarted` event in webview activity I need to update one specific item in my items displayed in recycler view, please note I need to update the items in client side not from database.

My webview activity:

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    setTitle(view.getTitle());
    String[] separated = url.split("&color=");

    LessonFragment  lessonFragment = new LessonFragment();
    lessonFragment.refreshItem(1,view);

    progressBaract.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Toast.makeText(webviewActivity.this, separated[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    progressBaract.setProgress(0);
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you refresh the item inside `onClick` event, before displaying the `webview`? Is that not an option?

Comment: @koceeng no that wont work, because, i am getting a itemPosition from a link parameters in web view (eg:index.html?position=3), and for this position i need to update the item in recycler view.

Comment: Did you find a solution. I am struggling with the same issue :(